# How to display Dictionary in ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

Hey, I've got a little problem with displaying my Dictionary in ListBox.

```
    public static Dictionary<String, List<String>> MyDict = new Dictionary<string,  
List<String>>();
    ...
    if(MyDict[value1] == null){
        List<String> Temp_List = new List<String>();
        Temp_List.Items.Add(sth);
        MyDict[value1] = Temp_List;
    }
    else if(MyDict[value1].Count < 4){
    ...
        List<String> Temp_List = new List<String>();
        Temp_List = MyDict[value1];
        Temp_List.Add(sth);
        MyDict[value1] = Temp_List;
    }
```

and I'd like to display in Page_Load (after logging) a ListBox which will have List from MyDict for this login. Eg.
Login is : sally
And list contains of: she, no, then
And after sally logging I'd like to see result like this:

```
she
no
then
```

and I cannot use BindingSource... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Example of dictionary binding:-

```
Dictionary myDictionary = new Dictionary
myDictionary.Add(1, "test");
myDictionary.Add(2, "test2");
```

value =1
text  to display = "test"
etc etc

dropdown bind:-

```
list1.DataSource = myDictionary;
list1.DataValueField = "Key";
list1.DataTextField = "Value";
```

list1.DataBind();

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a ListView?

```
private void PopulateListView(Dictionary<string, string> items, ListView lv)
{
    lv.Items.Clear();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in items)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(kvp.Value);
        lvi.SubItems.Add(kvp.Key);
        lv.Items.Add(lvi);
    }
}
```

Comment: The benefit of a ListView (from my experience lately) is the ability for more than two columns